# paypal "Ошибка на нашей стороне"

Tags: paypal

Делаю оплату через paypal на сайте через [Server-side REST integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/server-side-REST-integration/) . Иду строго по инструкции. Получаю токен, пользователь авторизируется и получает ошибку: **"Приносим свои извинения. Похоже, возникла проблема с нашей стороны"**. (как в скриншоте).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Звонил в поддержку, они сказали, что не работает, потому что аккаунт полностью не верефицирован. Но пробую тоже самое через верефицированный аккаунт, и получаю ту же самую ошибку...

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Позвоните в поддержку и скажите, что с верифицированного аккаунта та же ошибка.

Comment: Звонил. Говорят, что надо связаться с тех. поддержкой, а она только на английском. Писал запрос в поддержку, а они игнорят уже несколько дней... :(

Comment: У меня такая же проблема -- и тоже поменял на отличный акк а ошибка остается --- вы ее решили? Спасибо!

Comment: По счастливому (или грустному) случаю, заказчик приостановил работу по оплате)) Но PayPal мне ответили следующее: "Sandbox is constantly changing and the bug rate is pretty high at the moment, specially in REST API. This issue you report is not happening in LIVE environment at all and some changes were applied in a new push yesterday evening." Как хотите так и воспринимайте))